# Can two podman containers have same prefix for respective container ID?

Tags: containers, podman

Can two podman containers have same prefix for respective container ID?

I never faced such a situation.

If they have the same prefix - suppose the first 4 characters of the container IDs match, for example `a35d` and we try to remove them simultaneously using a single command, i.e.,
`podman container rm a35d a35d`, would we receive an error?